# NMHV 5 Gluon Scattering (Elvang and Huang, Ex 3.11)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, scattering, quantum-chromodynamics, spinors, helicity

In Elvang and Huang's [*Scattering Amplitudes in Gauge Theory and Gravity*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1308.1697), Exercise (3.10) (Exercise (3.11) in the printed version) asks the reader to construct the NMHV scattering amplitude of five gluons using the CSW expansion:

> **Exercise:** Construct $A_5[1^−2^−3^-4^+5^+]$ from the CSW expansion. Make a choice for the reference spinor |X] to simplify the calculation and show that the result agrees with anti-Parke Taylor formula.

So the exercise is to show that

$$ A_5[1^−2^−3^-4^+5^+]  = \frac{[34]^4}{[12][23][34][45][51]}.$$

Following the discussion around this exercise, we know that all contributing diagrams will be of the form

$$ (\text{MHV vertex}) \times (\text{on-shell propagator}) \times(\text{MHV vertex}),$$
which reduces the focus to four diagrams:

$$ A_3[1^-, \hat{p}^-_{15},5^+] \frac{1}{\langle15\rangle[15]} A_4[2^-, 3^-, 4^+,\hat{p}^+_{15}]$$

$$ A_3[1^-, 2^-, \hat{p}^+_{12}] \frac{1}{\langle12\rangle[12]} A_4[\hat{p}^-_{12}, 3^-, 4^+, 5^+]$$

$$ A_3[2^-, 3^-, \hat{p}^+_{23}] \frac{1}{\langle23\rangle[23]} A_4[1^-,\hat{p}^-_{23},4^+, 5^+]$$

$$ A_3[\hat{p}^-_{34},3^-,4^+] \frac{1}{\langle34\rangle[34]} A_4[1^-, 2^-, \hat{p}^+_{34},5^+],$$

where the "hat" denotes a shifted momentum. For general shifts $|X]$, this sum of diagrams looks horrible to simplify, with abundant use of momentum conservation and Schouten identities likely necessary.

> **Question:** Before embarking on the algebra (or turning to some Mathematica package to do it for me), is there some way to anticipate which choice for $|X]$ will be particularly rewarding?

By symmetry, I would be inclined to expect that $|X] \mapsto |2]$ might be a good guess, but I haven't had much luck so far with this choice or any other.

Does anyone have particular insight?

**Update:** I've confirmed the result above numerically using the Mathematica package [S@M](http://www.slac.stanford.edu/grp/th/software/) (associated preprint [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/0710.5559)), but I still lack a good choice for $|X]$ to make the exercise seem tractable analytically.

Answer (score 1):

*Answer:* After implementing the CSW prescription, it turns out that $\color{Red}{[1X]}$, $\color{Red}{[2X]}$, and $\color{Red}{[3X]}$ appear in various denominators of the 4 mentioned on-shell diagrams, so $X=1$, $X=2$ or $X=3$ are not possible choices for the reference spinor $|X]$. Letting $X$ be a non-trivial linear combination of $1,2,3,4,5$ generates too many terms. So the optimal choices are $X=4$ or $X=5$, which are linked by symmetry of the on-shell diagram. Below we sketched the calculation for $X=5$.

*Sketched proof:*  OP has already noted that the [CSW](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0403047) expansion contains 4 diagrams:

$$\begin{align}A_{15}~:=~& A^{MHV}_3(\hat{5}^+,\hat{1}^-,-\hat{P}_{15}^-)\frac{1}{P_{15}^2}A^{MHV}_4(\hat{P}_{15}^+,\hat{2}^-,\hat{3}^-,\hat{4}^+)\cr
~=~&\frac{\langle 1\hat{P}_{15}\rangle^4}{\langle 1\hat{P}_{15}\rangle\langle \hat{P}_{15}5\rangle\langle 51\rangle}\frac{1}{P_{15}^2}\frac{\langle 23\rangle^4}{\langle 23\rangle\langle 34\rangle\langle 4\hat{P}_{15}\rangle\langle \hat{P}_{15}2\rangle}\cr
~\stackrel{\begin{array}{c}\text{CSW}\cr \text{prescript.}\end{array}}{=}&\frac{\langle 1|P_{15}|X]^3}{\langle 5|P_{15}|X]\langle 51\rangle}\frac{1}{P_{15}^2}\frac{\langle 23\rangle^3}{\langle 34\rangle\langle 4|P_{15}|X]\langle 2|P_{15}|X]}\cr
~=~&\frac{[5X]^3}{\color{Red}{[1X]}[15]}\frac{\langle 23\rangle^3}{\langle 34\rangle\langle 4|P_{15}|X]\langle 2|P_{15}|X]}\cr ~\stackrel{X=5}{=}&0,\end{align} \tag{1}$$

$$\begin{align} A_{34}~:=~&A^{MHV}_3(\hat{3}^-,\hat{4}^+,-\hat{P}_{34}^-)\frac{1}{P_{34}^2}A^{MHV}_4(\hat{P}_{34}^+,\hat{5}^+,\hat{1}^-,\hat{2}^-)\cr
~=~&\frac{\langle \hat{P}_{34}3\rangle^4}{\langle \hat{P}_{34}3\rangle\langle 34\rangle\langle 4\hat{P}_{34}\rangle}\frac{1}{P_{34}^2}\frac{\langle 12\rangle^4}{\langle 12\rangle\langle 2\hat{P}_{34}\rangle\langle \hat{P}_{34}5\rangle\langle 51\rangle}\cr
~\stackrel{\begin{array}{c}\text{CSW}\cr \text{prescript.}\end{array}}{=}&\frac{\langle 3|P_{34}|X]^3}{\langle 34\rangle\langle 4|P_{34}|X]}\frac{1}{P_{34}^2}\frac{\langle 12\rangle^3}{\langle 2|P_{34}|X]\langle 5|P_{34}|X]\langle 51\rangle}\cr
~=~&-\frac{[4X]^3}{\color{Red}{[3X]}[34]}\frac{\langle 12\rangle^3}{\langle 2|P_{34}|X]\langle 5|P_{34}|X]\langle 51\rangle}\cr
~\stackrel{X=5}{=}&-\frac{[45]^3}{[35][34]}\frac{\langle 12\rangle^2}{[15]\langle 5|P_{34}|5]\langle 51\rangle}\cr
~\stackrel{(5)}{=}&~A^{\overline{MHV}}_5 \frac{[12][23]}{[35]}\frac{\langle 12\rangle^2}{\langle 5|P_{34}|5]\langle 51\rangle}\cr
~\stackrel{(6)+(9)}{=}&-A^{\overline{MHV}}_5\frac{I}{\Delta \langle 5|P_{12}|5]} ,\end{align} \tag{2}$$

$$\begin{align} A_{12}~:=~&A^{MHV}_3(\hat{1}^-,\hat{2}^-,-\hat{P}_{12}^+)\frac{1}{P_{12}^2}A^{MHV}_4(\hat{P}_{12}^-,\hat{3}^-,\hat{4}^+,\hat{5}^+)\cr
~=~&\frac{\langle 12\rangle^4}{\langle 12\rangle\langle 2\hat{P}_{12}\rangle\langle \hat{P}_{12}1\rangle}\frac{1}{P_{12}^2}\frac{\langle \hat{P}_{12}3\rangle^4}{\langle \hat{P}_{12}3\rangle\langle 34\rangle\langle 45\rangle\langle 5\hat{P}_{12}\rangle}\cr
~\stackrel{\begin{array}{c}\text{CSW}\cr \text{prescript.}\end{array}}{=}&\frac{\langle 12\rangle^3}{\langle 2|P_{12}|X]\langle 1|P_{12}|X]}\frac{1}{P_{12}^2}\frac{\langle 3|P_{12}|X]^3}{\langle 34\rangle\langle 45\rangle\langle 5|P_{12}|X]}\cr
~=~&-\frac{1}{\color{Red}{[1X][2X]}[12]}\frac{\langle 3|P_{12}|X]^3}{\langle 34\rangle\langle 45\rangle\langle 5|P_{12}|X]}\cr
~\stackrel{X=5}{=}&\frac{1}{[15][25][12]}\frac{\langle 34\rangle^2 [45]^3}{\langle 45\rangle\langle 5|P_{12}|5]}\cr
~\stackrel{(5)}{=}~&-A^{\overline{MHV}}_5\frac{[23][34]}{[25]}\frac{\langle 34\rangle^2 }{\langle 45\rangle\langle 5|P_{12}|5]}\cr
~\stackrel{(7)+(9)}{=}&-A^{\overline{MHV}}_5\frac{II}{\Delta\langle 5|P_{12}|5]} ,\end{align} \tag{3}$$

$$\begin{align} A_{23}~:=~&A^{MHV}_3(\hat{2}^-,\hat{3}^-,-\hat{P}_{23}^+)\frac{1}{P_{23}^2}A^{MHV}_4(\hat{P}_{23}^-,\hat{4}^+,\hat{5}^+,\hat{1}^-)\cr
~=~&\frac{\langle 23\rangle^4}{\langle 23\rangle\langle 3\hat{P}_{23}\rangle\langle \hat{P}_{23}2\rangle}\frac{1}{P_{23}^2}\frac{\langle 1\hat{P}_{23}\rangle^4}{\langle 1\hat{P}_{23}\rangle\langle \hat{P}_{23}4\rangle\langle 45\rangle\langle 51\rangle}\cr
~\stackrel{\begin{array}{c}\text{CSW}\cr \text{prescript.}\end{array}}{=}&\frac{\langle 23\rangle^3}{\langle 3|P_{23}|X]\langle 2|P_{23}|X]}\frac{1}{P_{23}^2}\frac{\langle 1|P_{23}|X]^3}{\langle 4|P_{23}|X]\langle 45\rangle\langle 51\rangle}\cr
~=~&-\frac{1}{\color{Red}{[2X][3X]}[23]}\frac{\langle 1|P_{23}|X]^3}{\langle 4|P_{23}|X]\langle 45\rangle\langle 51\rangle}\cr
~\stackrel{X=5}{=}&\frac{1}{[25][35][23]}\frac{\langle 14\rangle^2[45]^3}{[15]\langle 45\rangle\langle 51\rangle}\cr
~\stackrel{(5)}{=}~&-A^{\overline{MHV}}_5\frac{[12][34]}{[25][35]}\frac{\langle 14\rangle^2}{\langle 45\rangle\langle 51\rangle}\cr
~\stackrel{(8)+(9)}{=}&-A^{\overline{MHV}}_5\frac{III}{\Delta} .\end{align} \tag{4}$$

Above, in anticipation of the result, we introduced the following short-line notation:

$$ A^{\overline{MHV}}_5~:=~\frac{[45]^4}{[51][12][23][34][45]}~=~\frac{[45]^3}{[51][12][23][34]}, \tag{5}$$

$$\begin{align}I~:=~&P_{12}^2\langle 12\rangle[23][25]\langle 45\rangle\cr
~=~&P_{12}^2\langle 12\rangle[23]([23]\langle 34\rangle-[12]\langle 14\rangle)\cr
~=~&P_{12}^2\langle 12\rangle[23]^2\langle 34\rangle-P_{12}^4[23]\langle 14\rangle ,\end{align} \tag{6} $$

$$\begin{align}II~:=~&P_{34}^2\langle 34\rangle[23][35]\langle 51\rangle\cr
~=~&P_{34}^2\langle 34\rangle[23]([34]\langle 14\rangle-[23]\langle 12\rangle)\cr
~=~&P_{34}^4[23]\langle 14\rangle -P_{34}^2[23]^2\langle 34\rangle\langle 12\rangle,\end{align} \tag{7} $$

$$III~:=~[12][34]\langle 14\rangle^2,\tag{8}$$

$$\begin{align}-\Delta~:=~&-[25]\langle 45\rangle[35]\langle 51\rangle\cr
~=~&-([23]\langle 34\rangle-[12]\langle 14\rangle)([34]\langle 14\rangle-[23]\langle 12\rangle)\cr
~=~&[23]^2\langle 34\rangle\langle 12\rangle -(P_{12}^2+P_{34}^2)[23]\langle 14\rangle +[12][34]\langle 14\rangle^2\cr
~\stackrel{(6)+(7)+(8)}{=}&\frac{I+II}{P_{12}^2-P_{34}^2}+III
.\end{align} \tag{9}$$

Next note that momentum conservation and massless condition imply

$$\begin{align}\langle 12\rangle[12]-\langle 34\rangle[34]
~=~&P_{12}^2-P_{34}^2~=~P_{345}^2-P_{34}^2\cr 
~=~&2 P_{34}\cdot P_5 \cr
~=~&-\langle 5|P_{34}|5]\cr 
~=~&\langle 5|P_{12}|5].\end{align} \tag{10}$$

Altogether, we calculate

$$\begin{align}A^{NMHV}_{5}(\hat{1}^-,\hat{2}^-,\hat{3}^-,\hat{4}^+,\hat{5}^+)
~\stackrel{\text{CSW}}{=}&A_{15}+A_{34}+A_{12}+A_{23}\cr
~\stackrel{(1)+(2)+(3)+(4)+(9)+(10)}{=}&A^{\overline{MHV}}_5, \end{align} \tag{11}$$

which is the sought-for result.
$\Box$